# Bacula : How start multiple jobs at the same time?

Tags: linux, backup, bacula

I'm using the web interface baculum of bacula and I have a question :

When i want to run a job manually, I press the button "run job" but I can start only one job. But I have a group of 5 jobs that I want to run at the same time. Did you know if we have a way to start a "group of jobs" instead of running them one after each others ?

Did we have a way but only with the bconsole ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last I understood, there isn't a way to do this but my bweb knowledge is limited. You can typically (in the bconsole command line) create a job in one fell swoop using IE:

```
run job=JobName level=Incremental yes
```

Its also generally straightforward to make this work in a script, for example

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

declare -a JOBNAMES=(
  JobName1
  MyOtherJob
  AnotherJob
)

for job in ${JOBNAMES[@]}; do
  printf "run job=\"%s\" level=Incremental yes\n" ${job}
done | bconsole
```

Which should print out the results of each job.

Its also necessary that the director, storage daemon and file daemon being connected to have a valid `MaxConcurrentJobs` parameter to support multiple jobs at once and other factors such as volume interleaving or max jobs per volume are set.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I will try that :)